# How to process text between 2 chars

Tags: autohotkey

I want to type TeX equations in OneNote, send them to MathType (which converts it to MathML and has a more feature-rich editor) and send them back afterwards.

The sending, pasting, copying and sending back is no problem. However, I want to enter equations like `%a^2 + b^2 + \frac{2}{4} - \frac{3}{6} = c^2%`. As you see, I need the text between the `%` chars.

I already found the DynamicHotstrings.ahk, so my code looks like:

```
hotstrings("%(.+)%", "handle_equation")

handle_equation:
  WinActivate, MathType
  Send ^a
  Sleep 30
  SendRaw, $%$1%
  Sleep 30
  Send {Enter}
  Sleep 30
  Send ^a
  Sleep 30
  Send ^c
  WinActivate, OneNote
  Send ^v
return
```

Now I would like to paste things or have expansions (like typing `\mc5` to get `\mathcal{5}`) to make life easier, but Hotkeys doesn't support this.

Is there any approach which makes this possible? It would also be no problem if I could trigger a function after typing several equations and formatting them in one run. However, getting the text, splitting it and replacing it doesn't work since MathType gives a MathML object back, which OneNote understands fine.

PS: it would be cooler if you could also tell me how equations with `$` (so `$a+b=c$`) would be possible. I found no working regex for `hotstrings(...)` yet.

Thanks in advance, guys! :)

Comment: Interestingly enough, I don't get your version to work for me. Every backslash I type in the equation won't appear in the backreference variable **$1**. `hotstrings.ahk` seems to *swallow* them somewhere... Are you positive that those backslashes appear when you paste them back? Would be glad if someone else tested that.

Comment: @MCL It is because \ has a special meaning in RegEx and probably it is not escaped in hotstrings.ahk . Also dont use hotstrings.ahk with any edit controls that auto-completes as it breaks the thread of hotstrings() . I just saw that a hotstring() not working in Sublime Text works in Notepad, the only difference being ST autocompletes {} and Notepad not.

Comment: @sibbl If you look forward to use hotstrings(), I think you need to contact its author as it is clearly a bug or a missing feature of the function. For instance, try `hotstrings("%(.+)%", "%$1%")` and then type `%+%` anywhere . It should give the output as '+' but it gives **nothing** i.e. backspace-s %+% and enters nothing.

Comment: @Avi It is correct that \ and some other symbols are regex metacharacters, but why would user input be interpreted as regex? This makes no sense to me. How can you actually consume user input with hostrings() as is, without trimming metacharacters?

Comment: @MCL Sorry, hotstrings doesn't use user input as needle but as haystack. The code is really complicated and as it makes all the keys hotkeys, it has complex thread overlapping. I am not sure but I find that the function has 2 awkard notable behaviors. Type `%+a%` with the code above and you get a captial A which is same as `Shift+a` i.e `+a` in ahk. Another is with the `^`, it too returns very indifferent results.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! Seems like it simply is too complex for AHK. Just in case someone wants to achieve the same, I built a C# app using OneNote COM API now: https://github.com/sibbl/OneNoteMathType